# Display all incoming connections on my computer to block certain IP

Tags: windows-7, networking

I want to block a certain IP address at my firewall which is connected to my PC, but I don't know what it looks like.

Is there any way I can see a list of all IPs having connections with my PC?

So far I tried `netstat -b -n` in the command line, but from the list I get the only one showing appears to be the IP of a server that I don't want to block.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is. A command-line approach to this is using `netstat`. See [this](http://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm) how-to.

`netstat` is very similar to using netstat on Unix-based systems, by the way, so this applies not only for Windows.

Comment: thanks. And to block the IP I use the hosts file, right?

Comment: @Alex For blocking IPs you use a *firewall*. Host files are about resolving named addresses.

Comment: ok i found out this thing: http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/how-block-ips-using-windows-3638/#.UFO57WL57Qc

Comment: @Alex by default windows 7 firewall blocks all unsolicited attempts to connect to you PC, unless the ip is requested to make a connection from your end, this could be done a legitimate program or malware doing this. Exceptions can be made in the windows firewall program itself, you might see what exceptions are there.

Comment: well, here's the full story: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83384/how-to-find-ip-of-player-from-battle-net :(

Comment: they should block the ip on the game server, if hacker is smart they will adapt and change ip's making it near impossible to block if they are skilled. If battle.net cannot stop them I would stop playing until they resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

So I found out after all his IPs. Some guy HostBot from USEast posted [this](http://stopfrux.net16.net/fruxupdate/ListForBlockingFruX) link.

Here's how to do it:

- start => cmd
- type "mmc"
- file => add/remove snap-in
- select from the left "ip security policy manager", add it to the right and type ok
- now from the console root, right click "ip security..." and select "Create ip security policy", next, next, finish
- click "add" in the edit screen of your policy, and in the "ip filter lists" screen add a new filter.
- add new IPs to the list; leave the Source address as "any Ip address" and the destination must be "a specific Ip address or submask", where u enter each of the following:

  ```
  24.44.109.0/16
  67.81.254.0/16
  67.86.123.0/16
  ```

  - click ok, save all settings, then right click policy => assign...

Comment: Those addresses in the link are not /16. They are /32. a /16 is over 65,000 addresses

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also just install **[netcut](http://www.arcai.com/netcut/)**, which is a program used for checking your **"network security"** *(says in the app description)*, so you will list all IP-s on your network and easily cut 'em.

*(uses a special command that disables the network protocol of the device you cut)*

You won't exactly kick them, but you will block the user from using the data of the connection.

For an example, I live in a dorm and the speed is **5-10Kb/s**, so I use netcut and boost up my network by cutting others, the speed jumps to **200Kb/s**...

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive".